# pre-requisites for iphone development

Tags: iphone, macos, vmware, virtual-machine

I am having hp compaq notebook on which i have installed windows 7. I now wish to program for iphone apps. I have this knowledge that for iphone, xcode is the IDE on which apps are being created. I have Windows 7 installed in my notebook. I also know that iphone development requires Mac OS X.. Will VM Ware run MAC OS X? I mean installing Mas OS X on VM ware will help me?

Comment: **The prerequisite for iPhone development is a Mac running Mac OS X.** This question has been pounded into the ground. This isn't the website to help you find ingenious, unsupported, and illegal ways to get OS X running on a VM on your Windows box. Remember the license agreement for OS X explicitly **requires** Apple Macintosh hardware.

Comment: so i have to have Mac os x. is this it? no solution ?

Comment: You're missing the point. Who cares if VMWare will run Mac OS X? As soon as you try to install Mac OS X, you'll be forced to agree to its license agreement, which explicitly requires that you install it only on Apple hardware. Obviously, VMWare doesn't qualify. And like I said before, "how do I install Mac OS X in a VM" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @Cody: There there, I wouldn't go as far as saying illegal, the legal power of license agreements varies heavily depending on where in the world you happen to be.

Comment: thanx @cody.. i got my answer! thanx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OS X requires a physical Apple computer

Comment: Hoping to score the accept, since I only posted that as a comment?